# DataGridView does not contain a definition for 'Index'

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to run this code to get values from a DataGridView to a string array.

```
string[,] invoice = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count,dataGridView1.Columns.Count];

foreach (DataGridView row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataGridView col in dataGridView1.Columns)
    {
        invoice[row.Index, col.Index] = dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells[col.Index].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

I am getting this Error:

> 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'Index'

I don't own this code, I got this from [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SRNtCUp4CXc)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a wrong types inside the loop, try:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
```

and:

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this.

```
string[,] invoice = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count, dataGridView1.Columns.Count];
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
                {
                    invoice[row.Index, col.Index] = dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells[col.Index].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
```